# Is there a way to capture a bitmap from a WPF window using native C++?

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-c++, graphics, bitmap

Imagine a document window in a MDI application which contains a child WPF window, say a sidebar for example. How can one get a bitmap containing both the WPF pixels AND the GDI (non-wpf) pixels?

I've discovered that when making my thumbnail preview for the Win7 taskbar app icon hover, I get black in the parts of the preview where the WPF pixels should be. My current method simply grabs a bitmap capture of the document window. Then I get a DC for the preview, make a memory DC from it and select my bitmap into it. Then I do some size adjustments and bitblt the memory dc to the real dc. I'm guessing that the BitBlt operation doesn't take into account the fact that the WPF pixels are hardware accelerated and therefore need to be grabbed from the graphics hardware. All the stuff in GDI is managed just fine, though and when there's no WPF child windows, the preview image looks fine.

I'm wondering if it's at all possible to grab a bitmap of the WPF window from native C++. Then I can blt that onto the black area of the previous preview.

Comment: I'm thinking that since WPF is hardware-accelerated, there should be a way to get the pixels from DirectX. Not sure how I'd do that...

Comment: Is there a native version of RenderTargetBitmap?

Comment: I've been told that perhaps the best way to go is to create a C++/CLI interop layer that I can call into from C++ that will return a CBitmap for me. In that case, I can use RenderTargetBitmap to get the WPF pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I had to create an abstract class in native code containing a virtual method to get the bitmap that was implemented in C++/CLI. In the managed implementation, I used .NET's `RenderTargetBitmap` class to get a bitmap capture of the WPF window and then I filled up the passed in CBitmap object (see [How to get an BITMAP struct from a RenderTargetBitmap in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625170/how-to-get-an-bitmap-struct-from-a-rendertargetbitmap-in-c-cli)). In the unmanaged caller routine, I used the virtual method to obtain the Bitmap.

In short, there was no way to get the bitmap by simply using unmanaged C++ since WPF and GDI really don't work together for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your current approach correctly, but could you do a `BitBlt()` from the screen DC to your memory DC? You'd need to get the screen rect of your window, but that shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: That won't work with WPF since WPF renders to the graphics hardware, not to a device context. That is the process that I'm using so far and all I get is black pixels.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure exactly what your current approach was based on your question. I hope that you get a good answer to your question. :)

Comment: You could of modified your hardware level to less than 2, WPF would then produce software rendering.